# what does this sentence really mean?

Tags: meaning

what does this sentence really mean?

> ***it attempted to magnify the effects of growth
>   by reducing disparities in the distribution of assets***.

does it mean that:

> reducing disparities in the distribution of assets will magnify the effects of growth?

does it mean that:

> it wants to magnify the effects of growth because growth will reduce disparities in the distribution of assets and this itself is important?

[Yusuf, Shahid 2009. Development Economics through the Decades : A Critical Look at 30 Years of the World Development Report. p 35.](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/47108.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: It's great that you included your thoughts, but it might also be helpful to respondents if you include a source whenever possible. I believe [this is the source](https://books.google.com/books?id=baj6m0n0Fs8C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=it+attempted+to+magnify+the+effects+of+growth+by+reducing+disparities+in+the+distribution+of+assets.&source=bl&ots=Oj4xIYQkb1&sig=LIZ4hmMMwO9Vjx-4jZYmLZAZXBc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8vuztvLHOAhUH2WMKHUA8DLwQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=it%20attempted%20to%20magnify%20the%20effects%20of%20growth%20by%20reducing%20disparities%20in%20the%20distribution%20of%20assets.&f=false).

Comment: Thanks a lot  Max. I include my thought because I think this is the problem that many beginners like me have in learning English.

Comment: @jack What is the source of this sentence? Please edit your question include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really want to see the author explain the thinking in more detail. My guess at what is intended:

Growth produces an increase in existing assets. If assets are held only by a prosperous few, or the distribution is very skewed, then the increase in assets is experienced by only a few. If the distribution is more widespread, then the effect of growth is more widely felt as all asset-holders see the effect. The effect is magnified because more people see/experience it.

Comment: your are wonderful @djna. Thanks a lot for your really helpful guide.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into the economic argument...

The prepositional phrase is headed by **by**

> ...by reducing disparities in the distribution of assets.

*By*-phrases refer to method or manner, and thus they modify verb-phrases.

attempted to magnify the effects ... by...

The *by*-phrase says *how* the attempt to magnify the effects occurred.